# React-hooks does not update state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Some how match data is from the parent class, and I initialized matches using useState(match)
However, matches data is containing old data and wasn't updated as parent match data. Anyone help?

```
const FixtureDetailItem = ({ type, match, teams, isAdmin, postMatchesStart, putMatchesStart }) => {
  console.log(match)
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(match);
  const { homeTeamId, homeTeamName, homeScore, awayTeamId, awayTeamName, awayScore, scheduledAt, location, league, matchRecords} = matches;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('fired')
    console.log(matches)
    setMatches(matches)
  }, [matches]);
```

Comment: You're doing something wrongly. When matches is changed the effect going to re-fire because matches is its dependency.

Comment: Also instead of `setMatches(matches)` use `setMatches({ ...matches })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a circular connection between `useEffect()` and the `useState` - useEffect has a dependency of `matches`, then sets matches.

If you want it to change when `match` changes, then `match` should be the dependency.

Note that `useState(match)` only fires on the very first render. On subsequent renders, you must use `setMatches()` to change the value of `matches`.

```js
const FixtureDetailItem = ({ type, match, ... }) => {

  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(match);
  const { ... } = matches;

  useEffect(() => {
    setMatches(match)
  }, [match]);

  ... // JSX here

}
```

---

@James I though this might need some clarification.

See my statement above - ***useState(match) only fires on the very first render***.

On first render `useState(match)` sets `matches` equal to `match`.

Then the parent changes `match`, and because the match prop changed, the `FixtureDetailItem` function runs again, but React does not run `useState(match)` for the new value (by design).

It considers `matches` to be internal state of this component and leaves it with the old value.

Since `matches` does not change, the effect will not run - it only runs when one of it's dependencies change.

Comment: How can it be possible to implement internal state to use new value? once match is changed?

Comment: With `setMatches()` - that's what the `useEffect()` is doing.

Comment: by understanding what you've mentioned "It considers matches to be internal state of this component and leaves it with the old value" above code seems leave internal matches state with the old value, so child component isn't updated. Doesn't it?

Comment: No `setMatches()` can change it, but of course needs to be explicitly called.